# 70s (or earlier) book about a son looking for his missing father in the asteroid belt, who finds a hollow asteroid ship

Tags: story-identification, books

I read it over 40 years ago, so somewhere before 1976.

A father goes missing in the asteroid belt, his ship is taken back to Earth and his son returns to the asteroid belt to look for him and finds a hollow asteroid that's a ship.

I think he had a friend or his brother with him, when they fist landed on the asteroid they got out to look around, somehow the ship drifted off and they used their O2 tanks to reach the ship. They found a way inside and found few people inside in the middle of the asteroid, in an area big enough to have fields and animals.

The boys find their father after a long search. That is all I can remember, but there is a second book where the boys go to Mercury and find little people (about a foot tall.)

Comment: stories of hollow asteroids makes me think of Star Trek TOS "For the World is Hollow and I Touched the Sky" - the idea was also explored by Heinlein in "Orphans of the Sky" and Ellison in "Phoenix Without Ashes" (source: memory alpha)

Comment: Might it have been turned into an animated movie called  *Titan AE*?

Answer (score 9):

*[The Forgotten Star](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10343645-the-forgotten-star)* by Joseph Greene, 1959. The first in the Dig Allen series. Actually, his father's ship is found drifting in the asteroid belt with no one on board, and Dig is told about it; I don't remember whether the ship was brought back to Earth. And the asteroid is ... Eros!

[image: Book cover: man in space suit in the foreground, two people with space suits in a rocky background, and a ship and a planet in the space sky above them]

**Summary from Goodreads:**

> Here is an exciting tale of action and suspense, set in the world of tomorrow. As the story opens, two brothers, Jim and Ken Barry, are traveling by space ship from Earth to a new city on the moon. Aboard the space ship they discover a stowaway, young Dig Allen. Almost at once the three youths are plunged into an adventure that threatens to spell destruction for them all.
>
> Dig has set out to find his father, a space scientist who mysteriously disappeared months before. The Barry brothers agree to help Dig. Their search takes them to the "Graveyard of Space" and to Mars. There they meet Old Dorkas, the one person who is able to decipher the last message received from the missing man. Finally, the boys are forced to set out along in an unauthorized space ship. They soon find themselves marooned on a weird, forgotten world at the outer edges of the solar system where unknown to them, their greatest adventure is about to begin!

Comment: That' s it thank you very much

Comment: @MarkCurtis There's also a [Dig Allen home page](http://www.tomswift.info/homepage/indexa.html).